# How to validate specific child items using Knockout-Validation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using Knockout-Validation's [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/krob636/mcse71k2/57/) and added 2 child collections which contain validation rules.

```
var Item = function(id, name) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(id).extend({required: {message: 'item id required'}});
  self.name = ko.observable(name).extend(
  {
    minLength: {message :'item name must be at least 5 characters', params: 5}, 
    maxLength: 10
  });
   
   ko.validation.group(self, { live: true }); 
};

var itemsList = [new Item(1, 'test'), new Item(2, 'item 2'), new Item(0, '1')];

var viewModel = {
    items : ko.observableArray(itemsList),
    items2: ko.observableArray(itemsList),
    firstName: ko.observable().extend({minLength: 2, maxLength: 10}),
    lastName: ko.observable().extend({required: true}),
    emailAddress: ko.observable().extend({
        // custom message
        required: {
            message: 'Please supply your email address.'
        }
    }),
    age: ko.observable().extend({min: 1, max: 100}),
    location: ko.observable()
};
```

Using

```
ko.validation.group(viewmodel, { deep: true });
```

my child collections display the validation messages correctly, but I only want 1 child collection validated. The [documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validating-Only-Specific-Observables) says to pass in the items I want validated like:

```
ko.validation.group([viewModel.firstName, viewModel.lastName, viewModel.items]);
```

but when I do that, the child collection no longer displays the validation message.

To reproduce, go to the sample I linked above and click submit. Item 0 and Item 2 in both groups will have validation messages. Change

```
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel, {deep: true});
```

to

```
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group([viewModel.lastName, viewModel.items]);
```

Run again and click submit.

[image]

Comment: Hi.  If I add `{deep: true}` as this `viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group([viewModel.lastName, viewModel.items], {deep: true});`  I think it shows the same errors.  I this what you want?

Comment: @JoseLuis Hi. Thank you for the reply, but that is not what I need. I don't think I can use {deep: true} because that validates all of the child collections and I only want to validate 1 of the child collections. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Hi. Another question.  In your code, You are sharing the same observables in the two arrays.  If you declare another `itemsList2` as: `var itemsList = [new Item(1, 'test'), new Item(2, 'item 2'), new Item(0, '1')];
var itemsList2 = [new Item(1, 'test'), new Item(2, 'item 2'), new Item(0, '1')];`
And then you use them  `items : ko.observableArray(itemsList)` and `items2: ko.observableArray(itemsList2)`.  And also you add the `{deep: true} ` then it works as you say, Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/zw1jpqdy/.

Comment: Hey. Didn't even consider the shared variable being the issue. Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the ViewModel:

```
 var itemsList = [new Item(1, 'test'), new Item(2, 'item 2'), new Item(0, '1')];
 
 var viewModel = {
     items : ko.observableArray(itemsList),
     items2: ko.observableArray(itemsList),
```

you are sharing the same observables in the two observable arrays, that is, `items` and `items2`.

You could solve it by adding new observables (I add `itemsList2` and then I use it to initialize `items2`):

```
 var itemsList = [new Item(1, 'test'), new Item(2, 'item 2'), new Item(0, '1')];
 var itemsList2 = [new Item(1, 'test'), new Item(2, 'item 2'), new Item(0, '1')]; <---
 
 var viewModel = {
     items : ko.observableArray(itemsList),
     items2: ko.observableArray(itemsList2), <---
     ...
 };
```

Finally, you need to add `{deep: true}` in this sentence:

```
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group([viewModel.lastName, viewModel.items], {deep: true});
```

Here it is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw1jpqdy) as an example, and the full ViewModel.

```
var Item = function(id, name) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(id).extend({required: {message: 'item id required'}});
  self.name = ko.observable(name).extend(
  {
    minLength: {message :'item name must be at least 5 characters', params: 5}, 
    maxLength: 10
  });
   
   ko.validation.group(self, { live: true }); 
};

var itemsList = [new Item(1, 'test'), new Item(2, 'item 2'), new Item(0, '1')];
var itemsList2 = [new Item(1, 'test'), new Item(2, 'item 2'), new Item(0, '1')];

var viewModel = {
    items : ko.observableArray(itemsList),
    items2: ko.observableArray(itemsList2),
    firstName: ko.observable().extend({minLength: 2, maxLength: 10}),
    lastName: ko.observable().extend({required: true}),
    emailAddress: ko.observable().extend({
        // custom message
        required: {
            message: 'Please supply your email address.'
        }
    }),
    age: ko.observable().extend({min: 1, max: 100}),
    location: ko.observable()
};
```